# How to define a function which requires one of two parameters?

Tags: powershell

For the following function, it must have a parameter of `Group` of type int or a parameter of `Items` of type int array. How to define the function? It must have one of these parameters but cannot have both.

```
Start-Execute -Group 1
Start-Execute -Items 100,200,300
```

Comment: do You mean optional parameters? if that is the case can you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687550/create-a-function-with-optional-call-variabls-powershell

Comment: This is what parameter sets are for. See the `ParameterSetName` section of the [`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743%28v=wps.640%29.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use [Parameter Sets](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands.aspx), which are a feature of [Advanced Functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847806.aspx).

```powershell
function Start-Execute {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='ByGroup',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [int]
    $Group ,

    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='ByItems',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [int[]]
    $Items
)
# function code
}
```

Inside the function, you can determine which parameter set was specified by testing the value of `$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName` to see which parameter set it matches.

To see that your parameter sets were created correctly, run the following after the function definition has been executed:

```powershell
Get-Help Start-Execute
```

That will show you separate invocations for each parameter set.

That being said, we can't tell what your function does. If `$Items` is just meant to be an array of multiple `$Group`s (that is, a single `item` is the same as a `group`), then your function should accept a single int array `[int[]]` and then just always process it with `foreach`, because that will work correctly even with a single value supplied.

#### Adding a parameter to multiple parameter sets.

You asked about adding a parameter called `-Debug`. I just want to point out that `-Debug` is a [Common Parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884(v=wps.640).aspx), so you probably shouldn't use that name. I'll show an example using a parameter named `-Test`:

```powershell
function Start-Execute {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='ByGroup',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [int]
    $Group ,

    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='ByItems',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [int[]]
    $Items ,

    [Switch]
    $Test
)

)
# function code
}
```

This is one way to do it: don't provide any parameter set names. It will be available in all sets.

Another way is to provide a separate `[Parameter()]` attribute for each parameter set:

```powershell
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='ByItems',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='ByGroup',
        Mandatory=$false
    )]
    [Switch]
    $Test
```

This is useful when you want to use different settings for different sets, such as to make this parameter mandatory in one parameter set but optional in another, or to make the parameter available to multiple but not all sets.

Comment: Is it possible to add one parameter (for example, `-Debug`) to both Parameter sets without create two `-Debug` parameters for each set?