# In a PowerShell function, how can I make a parameter mandatory only if another optional parameter is absent?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, attributes, dependencies

I'm writing a PowerShell function and I need the first parameter to be optional, then the third parameter to be optional but *only if* the first parameter is present.

Here is the code as it is right now:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(position=0)][array]$From,
    [Parameter(position=1,Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$Names,
    [Parameter(position=2)][string[]]$Values
)
```

Ideally I would do this:

```
    [Parameter(position=2,Mandatory=(!$From))][string[]]$Values
```

But that is not allowed.
I've been getting the impression that using set names in some way is the way to go, but I'm not sure how I would go about it. The only thing I need to change is the Mandatory attribute value for $Values depending on the existence of $From.

What is the best way for me to do this?

---

I've looked over each of the following past questions pretty thoroughly and nothing I tried based on what I found in them would work.

[Create a function with optional call variabls: Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687550/create-a-function-with-optional-call-variabls-powershell)
[Requiring parameters in PowerShell when another parameter is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087469/requiring-parameters-in-powershell-when-another-parameter-is-present)
[PowerShell mandatory parameter depend on other parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533763/powershell-mandatory-parameter-depend-on-other-parameter)
[Having a optional parameter that requires another paramter to be present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131389/having-a-optional-parameter-that-requires-another-paramter-to-be-present)
[Multiple Mandatory Parameter Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382256/multiple-mandatory-parameter-sets)
[Conditional powershell parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748978/conditional-powershell-parameters)

Comment: I could be completely wrong but it sounds like you are trying to get a function with two different signatures, which doesn't really make sense! Can't you just ignore the third parameter in your code if the first isn't specified?

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 I suppose I could keep $From and $Values optional then in the code after Param() I could say if (!$From - and !$Values) {Write-Error "Values must be provided if From not provided" Error-Action Stop}. Long day at work, I guess I was too preoccupied with processing within Param() to consider other possibilities like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
[Parameter(position=0,ParameterSetName = "From")]
[array]$From,
[Parameter(position=1,Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName = "Names")]
[string[]]$Names,
[Parameter(position=2,Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName = "Names")]
[Parameter(position=2,Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName = "From")]
[string]$Values
```

You define two sets, `Names` and `From`

- `Names` has $Names and mandatory $Values
- `From` has $From and optional $Values

Comment: Oh that's very interesting! Very simple yet I don't think I would have thought of it on my own. I'll give it a shot once I get into work.